# Reverse graphics in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

### Issue and Question

I encountered that my graphics are all *upside down*. Now I have to mirror them in `pgfplots`. How can I perform this step?

It is no solution using the option `[y dir=reverse]` which also turns the axis label upside down (MWE):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y dir=reverse]
    \addplot graphics {GraphicsFile.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Appearance

This issue appeared due to the usage of `matlab2tikz` where in MATLAB. I performed the following command to correct the orientation.

```
set(gca,'Ydir','normal');
```

Now that I applied all changes/adaptations to my figures I do not want to go back. But maybe you could also give a short answer about improving my usage of MATLAB.

Comment: Setting matlab up to produce the correct orientation in the first place, as in the final part of your question, is probably the best approach.

Comment: But I guess that there must be a way to do that as with default `\includegraphics`, I can perform `\scalebox{1}[-1]{\includegraphics{GraphicsFile.png}}`. Somehow it should be performed to somewhat like `\addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\includegraphics{GraphicsFile.png}}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To flip your graphic, you can pass options to the `plot graphics/node` to scale the node vertically by `-1` and change its default anchor point:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[plot graphics/node/.append style={yscale=-1,anchor=north west}] 
      graphics[xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2] {example-image-a};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By default the node has anchor at `south west`.

Generally one can pass `\includegraphics` options to the via

```
\addplot graphics[includegraphics={options}] {image-file};
```

but no combination of the includegraphics options does a reverse of orientation, so we have to pass the options to the node instead.

Comment: Brilliant, as I thought there exists an "intrinsic way" to do it but I did not think of `yscale`, which would had been obvious after my comment above. Thank you! Nevertheless `\scalebox` is not an argument of `\includegraphics` but your last statement is nice to know.

Comment: @strpeter Good.  In the last comment, I was partly thinking of the `scale` option of `\includegraphics` which is less powerful than `\scalebox`.